# Files not opening after ubuntu 20.04 LTS installation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I am having a dell 3420 laptop with hybrid configuration(240GB SSD and 500GB HDD). The SSD used for the OS and HDD for file storage. Previously I was using Win 8.1 where the HDD was in dynamic mode. When i change the os to Ubuntu (Removed HDD while os installation), My HDD detected in Ubuntu. But most of the files in it were not opening.[error message shown while opening file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuiwP.png) .

Then i look in to the partition (the HDD were having 3 logical partitions(150GB, 150GB, 100GB) when i was using it in windows), the 3 partitions were shrieked into 100GB drives and some other partitions shown up with unknown format [HDD details shown in Disks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H92ht.png), [HDD details shown in GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dbH3.png) .

I tried ntfsfix on the partitions, but didn't work. Then i removed the HDD and connected to a windows 10 system and the system shows "invalid disk" error in disk management. I tried testdisk software in windows for file backup and it showed all the partition and files but i was not able to backup the file, so i didn't select recover lost partitions option since i was afraid of data loss. I  didn't make any backup of that HDD.

Is there any way that i can resolve this issue without any data loss??

Comment: Windows can't read the partitions? NTFS is a Windows/Microsoft proprietary file system, so `ntfsfix` in linux is really not the best tool for that job. I suggest looking into ways to image the disk so you can make a mirror copy of it as it is right now so if there is any further damage, you've maybe got something.  All of the activities you've mentioned so far can actually cause data loss, especially if you are flying blind (you can't identify the partitions on your drives).  It could also be a dead/dying hard drive, which is not your fault, but equally not easy or possible to recover from.